# Regular sequence maps to basis of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, regular-rings

Let $R$ be a regular local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. It is known that any elements $r_1, \ldots, r_d$ of $\mathfrak{m}$ which map to a basis for $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ as an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space form an $R$-regular sequence.

I am interested in a somehow reverse question:

> If $r_1,\ldots,r_d \in \mathfrak{m}$ form an $R$-regular sequence, when do they map to a basis of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$?

Obviously one needs $r_1,\ldots,r_d \not\in \mathfrak{m}^2$, but <del>I am not sure if this is sufficient</del> this is not sufficient as Mohan pointed out.

I am looking for a condition along the lines of "the ideal generated by $(r_1,\ldots,r_d)$ has to be $\mathfrak{m}$-primary and ...".

**Edit:**
Mohan's comment suggests that one has to look at the ideal generated by $(r_1,\ldots,r_d)$ and his example suggests that this ideal has to be radical. Together with being $\mathfrak{m}$-primary, this already implies $(r_1,\ldots,r_d) = \mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: What type of condition are you looking for? Keep in mind the example $r_1=x, r_2=x+y^2$ in $k[[x,y]]$.

Comment: The only salvageable part of my answer isn't worthy of an answer, so I'll leave it as a comment. Note it suffices to check for linear independence, since we know $R$ is an RLR, so $\dim R = \operatorname{depth} R = \dim_K \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$, i.e. $r_1,\cdots,r_d$ needs to be a maximal regular sequence.